# Moving between pages in QGIS Print Composer

Tags: qgis-3, print-composer, qgis-print-layouts

I'm using QGIS 3.6 Print Composer, and I managed to create a layout with two pages.

I now want to delete page 1. How do I move from page 2 to page 1 so I can delete it?

Comment: When adding a page using 3.10, it appears directly below the first page.

Comment: Thanks Erik. I see what you mean - if I add a page before page 1 I can see it - and delete it.  But looks as if I have an invisible page before my page 2 that I can't delete.  Annoying...

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot? maybe you already deleted page 1?

Comment: Yes that was the problem.  Yet it still printed out as a blank sheet when I sent the layout to PDF...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you (again) create page 1, as a blank the same size as page 2.

Then for each element of you layout, go to the menu "position and size" and change the page the element is displayed from 2 to 1. The element should smoothly move from page 2 to the same position at page 1. Then you may delete page 2 and wont have a blank sheet in your PDF.

Yes, this is a bit tedious, but still better than recreating everything from scratch.

Comment: Good idea.  Didn't think of that.